# Product Creation in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, product

when create on add Product then default automatic set customization option is open and radio button selected with three radio options ?

[image: this is possible automatic open and create When an new product]

Comment: Can you please add more details ?

Comment: i have need to add radio option but buy default its selected radio when an new product , add three radio option with my predefined radio option label..

Comment: i have done it by using aftersaveproduct observe.